# Lattice pattern

Tags: units

I'm trying to find and outline a non-primitive conventional unit mesh,  I'd also like to find any mirrors  planes and rotional symmetry axes.

[image]
 I first thought it would be like this: , but I was told the answer was smaller in a different thread.

[image]

This was the solution left by LDC3
[image]
Which one is correct? I don't know if his is correct because I thought the conventional unit mesh connected to points that looked the same as the original small pattern I picked(the small hexagon in the middle)

Also tried the axis of symmetry, but am unsure if 8 lines from the topside or 6 for a hexagonal pattern should come out.
https://imgur.com/Bkjwhih

I think for hexagonal structures there should be more lines
 like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuTVf.png

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112181/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wallpaper group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) classifies 2D patterns according to their symmetries.This looks like this is a member of group p6.

There is a 6 fold rotation symmetries about the center of the hexagon, but the blue section shows there is no reflection symmetry. Groups p6 and p6m are the only ones with 6 fold rotation. To be p6m, reflection would be needed as well.

[image: 6 fold rotation symmetry]

Here is a primitive unit cell that matches the illustration of the p6 group.

[image: Unit Cell]

And here is a view of the larger scale.

[image: Larger view]

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out why it's p6 and not p6m. I don't really see the significance of the blue highlight. So if I were to draw the axis of symmetry I would only have 4 lines extruding from half the center imgur.com/Bkjwhih like so rather than 6 because there is no rotational symmetry? It's hard to find info on the topic, really appreciated. imgur.com/ydMD80b

Comment: My only other guess for p6 would be something like this https://imgur.com/Ab2JaJC

Comment: There is rotational symmetry, but no reflections. If you reflect it about a horizontal line through the center of the hexagon, the blue spot isn't exactly the same. There are spots sort of like it, but not exactly. You can't do any other reflections through the center of the hexagon. If it was p6m, there would be lots of reflections through the center of the hexagon.

Comment: The primitive unit solution that you marked is different than dumpster's. Do you know why? Anyway, thanks, marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional unit cell (which generates the full lattice by translations) was already given by LDC3 in a previous answer to a duplicate of this question.

As for the primitive cell, it is $1/6^\text{th}$ the size of the conventional cell, since the conventional cell has $|G|=|C_6|=6$:

[image]

The $C_6$ symmetry can actually be seen on a graph of the image correlation function as a function of rotation angle:

```
data = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];(*Open the image file*)
data2 = ImageData[data][[1 ;; 737, All, 1]];
data3 = GaussianFilter[Image[1 - data2], 2];
data4 = ImageData[ImageRotate[data3, 0.000001, {1039, 1200}]];
f[k_] := ImageData[
   ImageRotate[data3, k, {1039, 1200}, Resampling -> "Nearest"]];
g[k_] := Plus @@ Plus @@ (f[k] data4);
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{k/(2 \[Pi]) 360, g[k]}, {k, 0.001, 2 \[Pi] + 0.001, 
   2 \[Pi]/450}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The triangle is the primitive in yours I can see, and it is indeed 6 times smaller, but mmesssser314 is saying  the primitive unit cell surrounds the squarish center.

Comment: DumpsterDoofus is right. I didn't see it.